# Programmatically change margin of an Ellipse C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0

I am writing a little Timemanagement Tool which shows when I can leave to fulfill my contractual working hours. 
The tool looks like this: [Tool Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HngGW.png)
I want to make it resizable, so i tried to set all form in relation of the window height and width. This looks like

```
     public void resizeElements()
    {
        clockBody.Height = this.Height / (300/248);
        clockBody.Width = this.Width / (300/248);
        double marginClock = Math.Round((this.Height - clockBody.Height) / 2);
        clockBody.Margin = new Thickness(marginClock);
        recHr.Height = this.Height / (300 / 50);
        recHr.Width = this.Width / (300/6);
        recMin.Height = this.Height / (300/80);
        recMin.Width = this.Width / (300 / 4);
        recSec.Height = this.Height / (300/118);
        recSec.Width = this.Width / (300/4);
    }
```

As you can see in the picture the  clockbody is not as big as the Window, so I tried to set it margin to   `Math.Round((this.Height - clockBody.Height) / 2);` but this throws an `System.ArgumentException` calling:

> 'System.ArgumentException' in WindowsBase.dll ("'Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto' is not a valid value for property 'Margin'.")

If i edit the code like `clockBody.Margin = new Thickness(26);` ((300-248)/2) I can run the Application. But thats not dynamic. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know that when you divide something by (300/248) you actually divide by 1? That's how integer division works. So watch out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use [`ActualWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) and [`ActualHeigth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) properties instead of `Width` and `Height`.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I can run the application now, but the margin isn't set correct. 
The Clockring you can see on the Pictrue is an ellipse in the windowclass and the clockbody is an ellipse in the usercontrol. The Ellipse is now centered but its not margin 26 :O